# How to call multiple methods defined in an Mason component?

Tags: perl, mason

Have two components: `test.mc` from I need call two methods defined in the component `name.mi`.

the component `/name.mi`

```
<%class>
    has 'name';
</%class>

<%method text>
<pre>Some text here</pre>
</%method>

<%method showname>
NAME: <% $.name %>
</%method>
```

the component `/test.mc`

```
<%init>
        my $namecomp = $m->load('name.mi', name=>'john');
</%init>
<% $namecomp->text %>
<% $namecomp->showname %>
```

Running the `/test.mc`:

- The `$namecomp->text`  method WORKS.
- The `$namecomp->showname`  NOT works, giving this error:

> Can't use string ("MC0::name_mi") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in
>   use at accessor MC0::name_mi::name (defined at
>   /.../testpoet/comps/name.mi line 2) line 5

The questions:

- can anyone show me an example how to use correctly the `$m->load($path)` ?
- why can't access the `$.name` from the `showname method` - so, how to call multiple methods defined in the `name.mi` component?

e.g., with want achieve something what in pure perl can (schematicaly) write as next:

```
package Myapp::Name;
has 'name';
method text() {
    print "some text";
}
method showname {
    print "Name: " . $self->name();
}
```

and use it as:

```
my $namecomp = Myapp::Name->new( name => 'John' );
$namecomp->text;
$namecomp->showname;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `construct` instead of `load`

From `perldoc Mason::Request`:

> ```
>    load (path)
>        Makes the component path absolute if necessary, and calls Interp load
>        to load the component class associated with the path.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>    construct (path[, params ...])
>        Constructs and return a new instance of the component designated by
>        path params, if any, are passed to the constructor. Throws an error
>        if path does not exist.
> ```

Load won't return a usable object while construct will.

The following worked for me in `/test.mc`:

```
<%init>
        my $namecomp = $m->construct('name.mi', name=>'john');
</%init>
<% $namecomp->text %>
<% $namecomp->showname %>
```